# Highcharts visualization tips

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to create a highcharts graph based on the second image in this dribbble mockup. Are there any good tips for how to add the white background to the most recent section? The shadow that area casts would be cool too, but I might be reaching.

I was thinking about plotting daily sales, so at the start of each day the area chart would drop down to zero. I thought I might be able to accomplish this by plotting an area chart for each day on the same graph and then nulling out the value when it should not be plotted.

This is my first foray into charting, so noting any other ideas would be appreciated.

https://dribbble.com/shots/1423171-Some-Analytics/attachments/208613

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at plotbands to sort out the white background:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotbands-id/

```
 plotBands: [{
            color: '#FCFFC5',
            from: 4.5,
            to: 7.5,
            id: 'plotband-1'
        }]
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands